# Saving files from StreamLit into a Temporary Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am trying to save uploaded files from streamlit into a directory so I can use them for other parts of my code. Here is the coding:

```html
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
st.write(temp_dir.name)

uploadedfiles = st.file_uploader("Upload a file")

if uploadedfiles is not None:
  uploadedfiles.save(temp_dir)
```

I keep getting this error:

```html
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/indextest/streamlit_app.py", line 17, in <module>
    uploadedfiles.save(temp_dir)
AttributeError: 'UploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Anyone know why? Would be much appreciated. I understand that it is saying that the uploaded file doesn't have the attributes to be used in .save but I need a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like:

```py
import tempfile
import pathlib
import streamlit as st

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
st.write(temp_dir.name)

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a file")
uploaded_file_name = "File_provided"
uploaded_file_path = pathlib.Path(temp_dir.name) / uploaded_file_name

if uploaded_file is not None:
  with open(uploaded_file_path, 'wb') as output_temporary_file:
    output_temporary_file.write(uploaded_file.read())
```

But I don't understand why you would want to do something like that because as soon as the script finishes, the file and the directory will be destroyed.